# Velocity $fn docs

Tags: api, documentation, velocity

I notice in some Velocity reports I'm working with that $fn contains some built in functions for Velocity. I can't seem to find a list of these. For example, `$fn.formatNumber($fn.duration($time),'##0.0')

My google-fu has failed me on this one. Anyone have link to the docs on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not built in. It is some utility class that either is getting added to every context somewhere or is registered in `velocity-tools.xml` as a custom tool.

Comment: You were right. We had a custom class that was being auto-imported to the context of all scripts.

Thanks for the pointer!